# MySQL: Filter Table and count multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

i have this (SQL)table:

```
dataId  userId  type
104     1   customer
105     5   interessted
```

Now i want a query to get for each user how much entry for each type exists.

Example if the user with the userID 10 have 10 entrys with type "customer" and 5 entrys with type "interressted".

```
userID    customers    interrested
10        10           5
```

How i can do this?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

You seems want *conditional* aggregation :

```
select userid, 
       sum( type = 'customer' ) as customers, 
       sum( type = 'interessted' ) as interessted
from table t
where userid = 10
group by userid;
```